# Evaluate String as Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

As part of a longer piece of code, I've made a formula into a string.  Now I want to go down a column and place that formula into each cell.  I am running into problems with getting the VBA code to evaluate my string as a formula.  When I try to evaluate the formula like this, I get a type mismatch error at the line where I try to evaluate.  Here's the part I'm having trouble with:

```
Dim commandstring As String

commandstring = [{=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))}]
```

I read that putting the square brackets around the formula will evaluate it, but I can't get it work.  Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Reverse your quotes. Make everything inside the quotes to be outside the quotes, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm still getting type mistmatch, I posted that change I made in the edit, maybe I moved the quotes around wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through and put the formula in to the cell formula.  Here the string is fixed.

```
commandstring  = "{=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))}"


Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lRow = 1

'Loop through and put the formula in each cell
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    ws.Range("B" & lRow).Formula = "{=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))}"

    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

Or if you really want to use it in a string variable.

```
ws.Range("B" & lRow).Formula = commandstring
```

Comment: Just to make sure - the Index/Match won't resolve, since you can't enter as an array like that - it'll just show that text in the cell?  (I ask because OP has manually entered the `{}`, instead of doing say `Range().FormulaArray = ...`).

Comment: @BruceWayne That is how I assumed they were using it.

Comment: Ah okay, I was just making sure I understood what the macro was doing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small function which takes a string as a formula:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Call to this function:

```
Dim commandstring As String

commandstring = "{=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))}"

commandstring = Eval(commandstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to piggyback off of ManishChristian's answer and recommend using

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Omitting "Application." before Evaluate gave me the following error:

> Automation Error: Catastrophic Failure

and corrupted my file. I'm not sure if omission correlates to error, but at least in certain applications it will so it is best to be safe.